# Ansible LookupPlugin: Change variables from plugin

Tags: python, ansible

A `LookupPlugin` is usually build like this:

```
class LookupModule(LookupBase):
    def run(self, terms, variables=None, **kwargs):
```

`variables` contain all the defined vars from Ansible.

Is it somehow possible to change these `vars` (or facts) directly from the `LookupPlugin`?